# Libgdx HTML5 Load on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, libgdx, embed

I've created a game using Libgdx and I am working with the html5 project. Everything works fine and I was able to put the game on my website. The problem I am having is that I want the game to be embedded, but only load it when I click a button. Right now I have it embedded and load when the page loads, thus making it very laggy. The way it is loaded right now is through:

```
<div align="center" id="embed-com.example.game.GwtDefinition"></div>     
<script type= "text/javascript" src = "com.example.game.GwtDefinition/com.example.game.GwtDefinition.nocache.js"></script>
```

If I put these lines in another html file (separate_html_file.html in the example below) and use jquery's load function, when I click the associated button a blank white page gets loaded.
Example:

```
 $('#thebutton').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#thedivtoloadinto').load('separate_html_file.html');
  });
```

But when I open that html file by itself it is not blank and the game shows up by itself.
I have also tried using

```
 $.getScript('com.example.game.GwtDefinition/com.example.game.GwtDefinition.nocache.js');
```

when I click a button and that also resulted in a blank white page.

So, is there any way I can have my libgdx html game embedded, but only load when I click a button. Thanks!

EDIT: To anybody who runs into this question with the same issue:

I ended up using iframes and putting the libgdx html game in a different html file. I then changed the iframe src when I clicked a button.